# MVC4 error: The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property

Tags: c#, json, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to deserialization a Resume which one string too large  using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. I am getting this error.

> " Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON
>   JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set
>   on the maxJsonLength property."

```
HttpResponseMessage messge = client.GetAsync("ladders/get/d381241a0ad596d4bf02f441e75d1891fcc482e607c751e3978bc0adea6a9d99").Result;
string result = messge.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
string  description = result;

     JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
     var myobj = jsSerializer.Deserialize<List<List<CandidateResume>>>(description);
```

This is my class

```
 public class CandidateResume
        {

            public string name { get; set; }
            public string url { get; set; }
            public string summary { get; set; }
            public string role { get; set; }
            public string compensation { get; set; }
            public string education { get; set; }
            public string expertise { get; set; }
            public string years { get; set; }
            public string relocation { get; set; }
            public string resume { get; set; }
            public string resumeExtension { get; set; }
            public string resumeMimeType { get; set; }

        }
```

I've added the maxJsonLength property to 2147483644, but it still doesn't work.

```
 <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
```

Comment: I have solved this way 
  JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer() { MaxJsonLength = 86753090 };                               
var myobj = jsSerializer.Deserialize<List<List<CandidateResume>>>(description);

Comment: This answer is the cleanest. I realize you posted this months ago, and perhaps you've seen this already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/can-i-set-an-unlimited-length-for-maxjsonlength-in-web-config/12278956#12278956

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this way . Its working fine for me .

```
JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer() { MaxJsonLength = 86753090 }; var myobj = jsSerializer.Deserialize<List<List<CandidateResume>>>(description);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this post 
[Can I set an unlimited length for maxJsonLength in web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/can-i-set-an-unlimited-length-for-maxjsonlength-in-web-config)

Try the following configuration, this is better practice than hardcoding the value in the code. Your config is missing one section

```
<configuration> 
   <system.web.extensions>
       <scripting>
           <webServices>
               <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647"/>
           </webServices>
       </scripting>
   </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

Edited since it also looks like you are using mvc4 add the following to your web config appsetting section.

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="150000" />
  </appSettings>
```

Comment: That's for web services. This post specifically addresses MVC4.

Comment: @JimSpeaker answer updated, his tags confused me originally as he states web services but from the looks of it he wants only the mvc solution.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to create this class:

```
public class LargeJsonResult : JsonResult
{
    public LargeJsonResult()
        : base()
    {
        this.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
    }
}
```

Then, in controller action, I just did:

```
return new LargeJsonResult { Data = grid, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
```

That's all.